# New job project 100,000s lines of code with no low level documentation

Tags: new-job

OK. So I have joined a new organization as RTL engineer (FPGA/ASIC front end work). The design that I shall be working on is literally 100,000s of lines of VHDL code and several dozens of very large sub-modules. It is part of a larger design implemented on ASIC.

There is no module level documentation and there are few or no comments in the source code. There are however a few high level presentations that explain the design at conceptual level. These do not help one understand how to dissect the highly complex source code with all the sub-modules inside it but do give an explaination on the purpose of the design as a whole in the system. These presentations also give a crude description of the main functions that are carried out but just short description, no details. However, none of this can be tallied to the 100,000s of lines of VHDL in any direct way.

The only thing for low level is the description of the interfaces on the different sub-modules. Nothing on purpose of or the internal working of the different sub-modules.

My boss has no idea about the internals of the source code, and it is clear that at most he only knows the stuff in the (recorded power point) presentations, nothing about internal working. There are testbenches source code but there are like literally 100s of testbenches that use UVM that implemented thousands of tests. I am not in verification team so I don't need to write testbenches but earlier I had thought about using them to run simulation and learn about the design.

Now I am being expected to learn about this design and then guide a junior engineer so we 2 engineers can improve the design or make changes to it. I have worked on several FPGA/ASIC designs in the past. However, this one is large and complex by order of magnitudes. The problem is not that it is large but not clear how to dissect it to understand it and complete lack of low level documentation. The biggest issue is that most people that worked on this stuff have left over the years and the handful of people that have some knowledge about it work in branch of a different country in a different team. Now when I joined, I had expected that I shall be given to work on a very localized part of this design since I am new, I do not understand it. But the boss is like, you need to be familiar with the whole design.

Should I resign from this job? I only joined a few months ago. What am I missing here?

Comment: Welcome to 90% of workplaces out there

Comment: Whats up with the downvotes?

Comment: That's fairly normal for an FPGA project this size, especially that the desired behaviour is mostly encoded as tests, because the alternative is a dedicated documentation team that follows development and updates everything as requirements and implementations change.

Comment: See the issue is not that the code base is large, the issue is that it is not obvious how to get about dissecting it. If was given a very specific task that add/fix function X, I would look at the very low level modules and only care about that region. But here I am supposed to become familiar with the whole design. Like what does that even mean?

Comment: @gyuunyuu you are getting downvotes because what you describe as a highly irregular situation, is actually very common.

Comment: The downvotes could also be because this question is very specific to the field of software engineering, whereas this stackexchange is generic to any workplace.

Comment: The downvotes can also be because questions asking for advice on a specific choice (in this case should I resign) are considered off-topic.

Comment: @gyuunyuu: What it means is that they expect you to work for them for an extended time, learning as you go. Seriously, you need to ask your manager to explain what they expect from you when; they are *not* expecting you to be an expert on their system by next Tuesday.

Comment: The main problem is, it is not clear how to actually learn this, there is so much interdependancy and abstraction involved that a new person just can't make sense of it.

Comment: You don't have to make sense of it all. You work on one isolated bit of function at a time and ignore anything that doesn't have to interact with it. (Well, modulo following rules for delta-I and other cases where there may be global side effects, but as I say there are rules to follow which minimize those risks.) You make mistakes, they come out in simulation and analysis, you correct them and learn from them. Welcome to the working world.

Answer (score 18):

Decided this is actually an answer, not a comment:

You don't have to grasp the whole thing immediately, maybe not ever. You need to learn the module you are working on.

Then the next module you work on.

Improve documentation as you go, where needed to help yourself and the next coder.

This is a necessary and valuable skill; accept that it is learnable and work to learn it.

Like it or not, you are going to spend most of your career interfacing with legacy code. Being thrown in at the deep end is a shock but running away is not a solution, just a decision to delay career growth.

Comment: This.   Eat the elephant one bite at a time.  Possibly tell the boss that this may take longer than he expects.

Comment: I agree with your eat elephant part, the question is, where to start? The level of complexity and interdependance is quite large. And the design works on very abstract data to generate more abstract data, it is not something that one can run and see in action.

Comment: You start with a specific task, suggested by your teammates as reasonably localized, possibly in pair programming mode so they can help you understand what you're seeing.  You ask them for help in understanding how to debug this kind of code, If it's something you don't have experience with; they must have techniques for doing so.  You accept that you are still a novice, and you learn

Comment: See also my answer to https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/191383/how-to-properly-replenish-knowledge-in-order-to-work-in-the-topic-of-space-techn/191384?noredirect=1#comment629346_191384

Answer (score 3):

> Should I resign from this job?

**Do NOT resign from this job unless you have already got a new job offer.**

If you have not got a new job offer yet, do your best with this current job while applying for new jobs elsewhere.

For the current job, you should clearly explain all the difficulties and challenges with your tasks to your boss.

You can try to ask your boss to allocate more time for you to learn and understand the legacy system. There is no magic here. It will take you some time to get familiar with the old code to the point that you would feel comfortable enough with the legacy codebase, and can adequately develop new code.

In the meantime, if there is anyone in your team or company who has worked on the legacy system, you could try to politely ask for help from them too.

Certainly, you can't ask the former developers to explain every single line of code to you. But, at least, you can try ask for some explanations about the main functionality of the big modules and how they interact with one another. They may be able to share with you some helpful diagrams, design documents, or notes.

Also, most likely, you don't need to be an expert in everything about that legacy system right now for this current project. Perhaps, you just need to learn about the main functionality of the sub-modules. Then, you can focus more on the modules that you are assigned to modify, upgrade, and enhance. **Take it one step at a time.**

Comment: The primary issue is that, the shear complexity of the whole thing is too vast to be grasped by one person in a few months time. There is no obvious way on where to start from. The top level interfaces themself have several dozens of pieces of information that they pass in and this leads to a very large number of possible input combinations. If I apply for another job, leaving this one just few months after, what reason do I give them?

Comment: @gyuunyuu - Think of a neutral reason, “it wasn’t a good fit for my career goals”, but it sounds like your ready to give up instead of identifying small problems that can be solved.

Comment: I just don't want to get fired, that is why I am thinking about what to do.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're likely to get fired, if you make an honest effort; you're letting yourself be more scared than you should be. It will take time to come up to speed. But that's true of any established project. Management knows this. Don't panic unless management tells you that they are dissatisfied enough that your job is at risk.

Comment: Re neutral reason: If you say "not a good fit for my career goals", be prepared for the followup question "Which goals where those, and how was it a bad fit?"

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction was: I wouldn’t be afraid of 100,000 lines of C code. I *would* be afraid of 100,000 lines of VHDL.

But then I worked at a company once that created huge chips. The designers wrote a spec. The simulator team wrote a simulator that exactly followed the spec. The driver team wrote a driver that followed the spec. The VHDL team designed hardware following the spec. So the VHDL team actually looked at a tiny bit of spec at a time and implemented it exactly. They didn’t need any deep knowledge. Just translate a tiny bit of spec, translate into VHDL, repeat thousand times. Simulator team worked about the same. Driver team needed a bit of overview to fit the pieces together.

If you run development like this, there is no need for fear. But that requires incredible patience and attention to detail.

Comment: Yes, 100,000s lines of C are atleast 10 times easier to grasp than VHDL if not more.